# fixing spring Kerberos version incomatibility

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-kerberos

I wanted to download `spring-security-kerberos-core.jar` for version mentioned in [this ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SES-98), i.e. `krb-1.0.0.RC1` or above. I can't find  the proper place to download it. The main site doesn't lead you anywhere but [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/extensions/krb/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, using Spring 3.1.0 and Spring-security-kerberos 1.0.0.M2.

My solution was to simply copy the "new" `org.springframework.security.crypto.codec.Base64` into a `org.springframework.security.core.codec.Base64` inside my own application. Not super-pretty, but it works.

AFAIK, there is still no newer release of spring-security-kerberos than the 1.0.0.M2.

Comment: Yeah Pap. I had the same solution and got it working. Still wanted to put a proper version for my upcoming release. Anyway thanks for your confirmation on release, that helps. Spring kerberos site doesn't give any clue.